# Swapping certain elements in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have some trouble trying to swap the first and third elements in a linked list. Here's my code with what I have so far;

```
void swap_first_third(struct node * A) 
{

   if(A == NULL || A -> next == NULL)
   {
     return;
   }
   else
   {  
     struct node* prev = A;
     struct node* curr = A -> next;

     A = curr;

     while(1)
     {
        struct node* next = curr -> next;
        curr -> next = prev;

        if( next == NULL || next -> next == NULL)
        {
            prev -> next = next;
            break;
        }

        prev -> next = next -> next;

        prev = next;
        curr = prev -> next;
     }

}

}
```

This is the list I'm supposed to swap;

```
15          100         5           100         30
```

However, this is my result when I implemented the swap function;

```
5           100         30          100
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the goal is simply to swap the first and third elements, you don't need the `while(1)` loop.

Comment: Okay but asides from removing the while loop, do I change anything else?

Comment: Most of the body of the `while` loop can be removed after removing the `while` loop. BTW, in the first `if` statement, you should check for `A->next->next == NULL`. If `A->next->next` *is* NULL, then there is no third element, and there's nothing to do.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do.  Would it be easier to just swap the values of the 1st and 3rd nodes and leave the next pointers alone?

Comment: I can do it by swapping but I have to adjust the links

Comment: What a linked list is this, a single or double linked list? Please provide the definition of `struct node`. A [example] would be very helpful, too.

Comment: First draw a diagram for yourself which shows all affected nodes and the pointers between them and the rest. Then think about what to change to swap both nodes. Finally create code that does it.